# MPLAB X IDE - Script Engine is not Supported

Tags: pic, mplab-x

In using the Pickit4 for flashing the code.

When I first open the MPLAB X IDE and use the Make and Flash button to flash the MCU, it works fine.

But the next time in the same session, the Make and Flash button goes grey and does not do anything and I get and error saying:

> Failed to initialize PICkit 4.

Then when I try to clean and build, I get an error saying:

> Script engine is not supported.

I have tried deleting the persistent files and starting fresh, but the errors remain. I tried with multiple different projects, but I still have the same issue.

I'm not sure what do do next?
Is it a PICkit 4 issue?
How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to update the MCC plugin. The older MCC is not working well with the newest MPLABX

Comment: It may be an IDE issue as well. Please consider providing the following informations: The OS i.e. Windows 10 or Linux, MPLABX IDE version, the MCU model.

Comment: Windows 11 and PIC18F4331.

Comment: What happens if you remove the PICKit and switch to "simulator" ?

Comment: And if it works switch back to PICLit afterwards.

Comment: I tried that. At first I suspected this was a PickKit 4 issue, but the same happened when I switched to simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started seeing the same thing today. Worked fine for months until now. No MCC installed. Turns out some packs were out of date. I updated them and everything is back to normal so far.

PicKit 4
Product Version: MPLAB X IDE v6.05
Windows 10 Pro 22H2
PIC16F887

Comment: Great! I'll try that. How do you check for pack updates?

Comment: From the "Tools" menu, select the "Packs" option. You should see a list of installed packs and those that need updating.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of the MCC:
If you want to work with MPLABX5.05 you need MCC 5.2.2 (or the other way around)
It also may be neccessary when upgrading to MPLAB X IDE v6.05/MCC v5.2 on an existing MCC Classic configuration it may be necessary to update your MCC libraries for some GUIs to display properly

Comment: I'm currently using v6.05 and even tried updating everything.